# Regex to match multiple line of new line character

Tags: regex

I have written a regex to match from **locale="en"** to **date slot="164"** but my regex is not matching multiple new lines. Please advice.

**regex**

```
locale="en"\s>\n<string slot="157">(.*|\n)*slot="164"
```

**matching string**

```
<case id="1" casebase="1" name="K" locale="en" >
<string slot="157"><value>1asw</value></string><enum slot="12"><value id="1" name="Incomplete" /></enum><integer slot="9963"><value>2</value>
</integer><string slot="9960"><value>
07/12/18 16:51  a created with status Incomplete by a &lt;br/&gt;

</value></string><string slot="9961"><value>awd</value></string><string slot="160"><value>awd</value></string><date slot="161"><value>2018-07-12T20:51:34</value>
</date><date slot="164"><value>2018-07-12T20:51:34</value>
</date></case>
```

[image: suggested regex]

Comment: Use `(.*?)` with an appropriate modifier (or `([\s\S]*?)`) instead of a `(.*|\n)*`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried your suggestion but that doesn't seem to work. Attached screenshot.

Comment: You did not use ***my*** suggestion. `locale="en"\s>\n<string slot="157">(.*?)slot="164"` is what I suggested (with *`.` Can Match Newline Characters* option ON).

Comment: It's not matching till the slot I want to , it's matching only first two lines.

Comment: See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/PFq3d0/1), the solution works well.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Thank you for quick reponse , yes it does work on the website you have used for the demo, it worked for me too earlier but the same is not working   in Notepad++ or emeditor. I am not able to understand the difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197332/discussion-between-skr-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: `locale="en"\s>\n<string slot="157">(.*?)slot="164"` works in Notepad++ with *`.` matches newline*. It works everywhere with the right option turned on.